# Update rows where IN SELECT does not update - TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to update rows in a query result (T-SQL - SQL Server 2016), using the below query, but eventhough the SELECT returns 5 rows, it gives me the result `(0 rows affected)`.

All articles I have found regarding this have not given me a clue on what I am missing.. anyone that can direct me to a solution? :-)

```
UPDATE MessageCenter_Receiver SET Displayed = 1 
WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT MessageCenter.id FROM MessageCenter 
INNER JOIN MessageCenter_Receiver ONMessageCenter.id = MessageCenter_Receiver.MessageID 
WHERE (MessageCenter_Receiver.UserID = 65) 
AND (MessageCenter.MessageSender = 'mmm') 
AND (MessageCenter_Receiver.Displayed IS NULL OR EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver.Displayed = 0));
```

Comment: Please provide sample data sufficient to make a Minimal, Reproducible Example per this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you are trying to match MessageCenter_Receiver.ID against MessageCenter.ID; the fact that there are 5 MessageCenter.ID returning by the subquery doesn't necessarily mean that there are matches  in MessageCenter_RECEIVER.ID

Comment: Good point @Jayvee  .. I need to use another key for it .. I will test and return.

Comment: OK, its official, I am an idiot or just tired .. correct @Jayvee `MessageCenter_Receiver.ID` should be `MessageCenter_Receiver.MessageID`, now I get 5 rows updated .. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: you're welcome, sometimes we just need another pair of eyes

Comment: Exactly, we stair blind sometimes :-)